# R replacing spaces with periods in raster stack plot

Tags: r, plot

I have a raster stack that I would like to plot in individual plots with individual titles. I rename the raster stack and plot:

```
names(raster_stack) <- c("Annual Mean Temperature",
                         "Mean Diurnal Range",
                         "Temperature Annual Range",
                         "Annual Precipitation",
                         "Precipitation of Wettest Quarter",
                         "Precipitation of Warmest Quarter")
plot(raster_stack)
```

It plots fine, except that all the titles have the spaces replaced with periods:
[image]
I understand that this is because R is making sure the raster names are valid strings for objects (no spaces). To return spaces to the plot titles I could either rename the plots manually (use a vector of names with spaces) or find a to force the spaces in the object names (a bad idea, I believe?). I just can't find out how to do either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can force spaces into the layer names, however, the other approach you suggest should work like this:

```r
layer.names <- c("Annual Mean Temperature",
                 "Mean Diurnal Range",
                 "Temperature Annual Range",
                 "Annual Precipitation",
                 "Precipitation of Wettest Quarter",
                 "Precipitation of Warmest Quarter")

par(mfrow=c(2, 3))
for (i in seq_len(nlayers(raster_stack))) {
  plot(raster_stack[[i]], main=layer.names[i])
}
```